# Export pdf, imagesize changed

Tags: export

```
fig = Show[ Plot[y = x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}]]
```

(1). Right click the figure and choose "Save Graphics As"->pdf, the file size is 400points* 400points. There is no problem here.

(2). Export[fig.pdf,"PDF"], the file size is 400points* 400points. There is no problem here.

```
fig = Show[ Plot[y = x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"y=x"},  ImageSize -> {400, 400}]]
```

(1). Right click the figure without the legend and choose "Save Graphics As"->pdf, the file size is 400points* 400points. There is no problem here.

(2). Export[fig.png,"PNG"], the file size is 400points* 400points. There is no problem here.

(3). Export[fig.pdf,"PDF"], the file size is **338points* 290points**. The problem is here.

[image]

How to make the exported pdf with legend with size 400*400 in this case?

My computer monitor is 14'', 1600*900. The pdf reader is Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Where did you get your screenshot? Is that from Acrobat or MMA?

Comment: The screenshot is from Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

I have know the answer. Add one line at the beginning.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"];
```